# Obtain the Authentication (Principal) object via oAuth2 Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

So I was confused at first thinking about which custom AuthenticationManager or even custom AuthenticationProvider I could implement after a user obtains an authorized JWT on their client device from going through the Authorization Server in an oAuth2 environment.

Then it hit me, duh, the user doesn't need to go through an AuthenticationManager because they've already been "authenticated" through the Authorization Server using whatever oAuth2 flow is implemented in the system. They have the JWT access token to prove it, and in fact, they won't even be able to hit any Resource Server endpoints without an authorized access token.

However, I would still like a way to access the Authentication object that holds all the User information.

How would you go about creating and getting a reference to this Authentication object without having used an AuthenticationManager? I'm pretty confused here.

The main reason I want this Authentication object is because I plan to use method level security with custom expressions alongside Spring Security's ACL. In other words, I want oAuth2 and I also want to use an ACL to have very fine granular control over which users have authorizations/permissions over which domain objects.

So how do I get access to this Authentication object (perhaps even creating it with the user's current access token as a field/property) after having set up oAuth2?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has following Controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
Output do(Input input)
```

You can add Authentication object to the Parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
Output do(Input input, Authentication authentication)
```

Spring will wire this dependency automatically.
If you are in a deeper layer / other class, you can use

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()
```

Comment: So let me understand. Using oAuth2 with Spring Security will automatically construct the Authentication object, and set it in SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication()?

If true, then 1) what AuthenticationManager implementation is it using to do this? 2) If it is an AuthenticationProvider instance, which implementation is it? 3) What UserDetailsService implementation behind the scenes is checking that the token being sent in the request header is valid, and then also extracting from the data source the username and other credentials that belong to the token's resource owner?

Comment: Sry, wasn't online last days. Yes Spring will automatically create this object based on the contents of the authentication token. You 'll normally have to provide your own UserDetailsService implementation.

I have made an example with simple DB login and oauth2 here: https://github.com/miwoe/spring-security

But it is not well documented. It is based on this: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js